# Testing client connection on the server side with websockets in mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, socket.io, mocha.js

I made a simple example app using socket.io library and now I would like to test that my `io.on("connection")` is called when a client connects.

So I created a simple fake client in my unit test that sucessfully connects to the server, but the spy that watches the method `handleSocket` triggered by `io.on("connection")` says it has never been triggered, which it clearly has been according to the logs.

It is probably a timing/async issue that I can't figure out.

Server-side code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env["PORT"] || 3030;
var io = require("socket.io").listen(port);
io.on("connect", socket => handleSocket(socket));
function handleSocket(socket) {
  console.log("a user connected", socket.id);
}
exports.io = io;
exports.handleSocket = handleSocket;
```

The actual unit test in mocha:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var sinon = require("sinon");
var ioClient = require("socket.io-client");
process.env["PORT"] = 3030;
process.env["VERBOSE"] = true;
var options = {
  transports: ["websocket"],
  "force new connection": false
};
describe("server.spec", function() {
  this.timeout(5000);
  it("Client should connect", function(done) {
    app = require("./server2");
    let spy = sinon.spy(app.handleSocket);
    var client = ioClient.connect("http://localhost:" + process.env["PORT"], options);
    client.on("connect", function() {
      expect(spy.called).to.be.equal(true);
      client.disconnect();
      app.io.close();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Test - fails, the spy.called is equal to false 
Log output:

```
  server.spec
a user connected jopFRhcfzjkC_TjsAAAA
Spy was called: false
    1) Client should connect
a user connected uIpW2gsiljJkS4wFAAAB
Spy was called: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the documentation here: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.5.0/spies/, in the section on creating spies is a little unclear for this use case:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(myFunc);
```

If you create a spy that way it means that `spy` is it self the function you would need to call. I.e., it creates a proxy around myFunc, but it does not actually use that proxy if you call myFunc directly. What you need is this: `var spy = sinon.spy(object, "method");`, so your example would become:

Server Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env["PORT"] || 3030;
var io = require("socket.io").listen(port);

exports.handleSocket = function(socket) {
  console.log("a user connected", socket.id);
};

// NOTE: we use handleSocket as method of exports here
io.on("connect", socket => exports.handleSocket(socket));

exports.io = io;
```

test spec:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var sinon = require("sinon");
var ioClient = require("socket.io-client");
process.env["PORT"] = 3030;
process.env["VERBOSE"] = true;
var options = {
  transports: ["websocket"],
  "force new connection": false
};
describe("server.spec", function() {
  this.timeout(5000);
  it("Client should connect", function(done) {
    app = require("./server2");
    let spy = sinon.spy(app, "handleSocket"); // <- CHANGED CODE
    var client = ioClient.connect("http://localhost:" + process.env["PORT"], options);
    client.on("connect", function() {
      expect(spy.called).to.be.equal(true);
      client.disconnect();
      app.io.close();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

When you create a spy this way it actually replaces the method (`handleSocket`) on the object (`app`) which is the same object as the exported object from your server code.

Comment: This does work, cheers! Would you mind explaining a little bit more, how does that make the event call the right (wrapped by spy) method?

Comment: When you call `sinon.spy(app,"handleSocket")` you are replacing app.handleSocket with a new function (the spy) that will call the original function when called, but has the extra functionality that you would expect of a spy (keeping track of number of calls, arguments, etc). Since the `app` object in your test spec is the very same object exported in your server code, you are also effectively replacing the `exports.handleSockets` function in your server code with that same spy. `exports.handleSockets` is what is used as the event handler. Let me know if that clarifies it.